# Problem importing csv file with special caracters to MYSQL db

Tags: php, mysql, csv, codeigniter, import

So i'm trying to import a CSV format file of my leads using codeigniter/php. The problem is that the Lead_name column container rows with special caracters (arabic letters). Whenever i insert the data to the DB i get something like this : Ø§ÙˆÙƒÙŠÙ„ ÙÙˆØ²ÙŠØ©
Please i need help !
I have the db config file in codeigniter like this :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'crm_app',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

The form element

```
<form id="myFormImport" method="post" id="import_csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Selectionner Fichier CSV</label>
        <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" required accept=".csv" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="import_csv" class="btn btn-primary" id="import_csv_btn">Import CSV</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is an actual picture of the db table
[image]

I tried even adding this to my header

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");?>
```

Please note that i'm using the csvimport library !

seems like everything is set to utf8_general ci, so please help me figure out where's the problem ! i'll provide everything you need me to provide !

as asked below here's my import script in the controller

```
public function ImportClient(){
    $file_data = $this->csvimport->get_array($_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"]);
    foreach($file_data as $row)
    {
    $Clientinfo[] = array(
        'NomClient' => $row["Nom Complet"],
        'TelClient'  => $row["Tel"],
        'WilayaClient' => $row["Wilaya"],
        'CommuneClient'   => $row["Commune"],
        'AdresseClient'   => $row["Adresse"],
        'TelevendeuseID'   => 1,
        'LivreurID'   => 1,
        'StatusLivraison' => 1,
        'InvoiceID'   => 10,
        'StatusID'   => 1,
        'Source'   => $row["Source"],
        );
    }
    $result = $this->m->import($Clientinfo);
}
```

importing the library

```
function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('leads_list', 'm');
        $this->load->library('csvimport');
}
```

Comment: Where is your import script?

Comment: @aynber added ! but the problem isn't the script ! everything is working smoothly , the data get inserted , the problem is how it's stored !